# Process builder - Scheduled Actions Issue

Tags: process-builder

We have Built Process builder Has below. The issue is that some of the process builder Actions are executing but some are not  - I am really having a tough time debugging this.

Criteria : 
Due-date >= Today.

you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record? - **Yes**

Scheduled Action - 
1 day After the due-date send Reminder email.

Comment: remember that process Builder only executes upon DML to the record.  SFDC will not monitor an object for changes (duedate > today) unless you set up scheduled actions upon some prior DML event for that record

Comment: Hi cropredy by criteria i meant DML events , when ever a record is created or updated to have due-date >= Today then it we execute scheduled action one day after the due date

Answer (score 0):

After Some Digging we found that even though the records are updated one by one and processbuilder actions should have been executed one after the other , Salesforce groups the similar actions together. Meaning All the record ids are being passed to the invockable  class as list. Since my class itself is not properly bulkified , The records are falling through.